# Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'X' not found when trying to create a data frame

Tags: r

I have a problem to create a data frame. 
dat1 is perfect, but when I try to create dat2 I get this error message:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Dia' not found
```

This is my code:

```
install.packages("magrittr") 
library(magrittr)

install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

library(cowplot)

install.packages("usethis")
library(usethis)

install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)

install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

library(dplyr)

devtools::install_github("larmarange/JLutils" , force= TRUE)
library(JLutils)


install.packages("rio")
library(rio)

dat <- rio::import("https://github.com/jincio/COVID_19_PERU/blob/master/docs/reportes_minsa.xlsx?raw=true")

dat1 <- dat %>%
  mutate(pos_new = Positivos-lag(Positivos,default = 0),
         des_new = Descartados-lag(Descartados,default = 0)) %>%
  group_by(Dia) %>%
  summarise(pos_new = sum(pos_new), des_new = sum(des_new)) %>%
  mutate(cum_pos = cumsum(pos_new),
         tot_pruebas = pos_new+des_new)
```

Here comes the problem:

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>%
  mutate(neg_new = tot_pruebas-pos_new) %>%
  dplyr::select(Dia, pos_new, neg_new) %>%
  rename(Positivo = pos_new, Negativo = neg_new) %>%
  gather(res, count, -Dia) %>%
  uncount(count)
```

I get this error : Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'Dia' not found

Comment: I can't rreproduce the error

Comment: @akrun Did you get the same error message?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get any errror